# SQL Server says user created but does not appear in user tables in VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

After getting the parameters to work, I've been stuck and wondering on this by the way I'm a newbie that is why I really don't know what to do now.

Here is my code. It is working in a way but the user info I created or try to insert doesn't seem to appear on the `User` table, it does say that the user info has been stored though. I think I've been running in circles thanks in advance for the help

```
    Dim userType As String = ComboBox9.Text
    Dim empNum As String = eeNum.Text
    Dim pass As String = passWord.Text
    Dim lastName As String = lName.Text
    Dim firstName As String = FName.Text
    Dim midInitials As String = midIni.Text
    Dim nameEx As String = nameExt.Text
    Dim pos As String = Position.Text
    Dim nickN As String = nickName.Text
    Dim contact As String = contNum.Text
    Dim email As String = eM.Text
    Dim residentAdd As String = resAdd.Text
    Dim str As String = String.Empty

    Using Conn As New SqlConnection

        Conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\IASDIRMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;ConnectRetryCount=3;ConnectRetryInterval=3"

        str &= "INSERT INTO [User] ([EE Number], [Last Name], [First Name], [Middile Initials], [Name Extention], [Position], [Nickname], [Contact Number], "
        str &= "[Email Address], [Residential Address], [Password], [User Type])"

        str &= "VALUES (@empNum, @lastName, @firstName, @midInitials, @nameEx, @pos, @nickN, @contact, @email, @residentAdd, @pass, @userType)"


        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(str, Conn)

            If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

                Conn.Open()

            End If

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userType", userType)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empNum", empNum)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@midInitials", midInitials)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nameEx", nameEx)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pos", pos)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nickN", nickN)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contact)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@residentAdd", residentAdd)

            Try

                If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().Equals(1)) Then

                    MsgBox(" User Successfully Created !! ")

                    eeNum.Clear()
                    passWord.Clear()
                Else

                    MsgBox(" Error Creating User  !! ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

                    eeNum.Clear()
                    passWord.Clear()

                End If

                cmd.Parameters.Clear()

            Catch ex As Exception

                MsgBox(" Error on Connecting to the Database ! ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

            End Try

        End Using

        Conn.Close()

    End Using
```

Comment: Most likely the data is where it is supposed to be but you're just not looking for it properly, which is a very common issue.  How EXACTLY are you determining that the data is not in the table?  Are you aware that your application is not using the database in your project folder?  Are you aware that the database it is using gets overwritten each time you build your project?

Comment: By the way, your error message is misleading.  If an exception is thrown your say "Error on Connecting to the Database" but your `Try` block doesn't actually start until after the connection is opened.  That means that your app will crash if there actually is an error when connecting and if you catch that exception then cause is something other than an error connecting.

Comment: about the "how exactly am I determining that the data is not in the table".. after I fill out the textboxes and hit the save button it seems like my codes work but then whenever I check on the User table where it supposed to be stored..its not there. and nope im not real sure and pretty much not aware  that my application is not using the database in my project folder. i use VS 2012 by the way. sorry im just a newbie and I only learn on tutorials on the internet

Comment: in addition, before i run the project, my database.mdf is still connected but whenever i start to run the project I notice that the indicator changes from connected to disconnected and also there is no error/s popping out... sigh* im really at loss here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly you're just looking in the wrong database.  You can read Microsoft's take on managing local data files [here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx).

To summarise, when you add a data file to your project, it gets added to the project folder along with all the other source files.  It is supposed to stay clean, ready for deployment.  That's where you make schema changes and add only default data, e.g. reference lists.

When you build your project, that source data file gets copied to the output folder along with your EXE.  When you run your project, it's that copy in the Debug output folder that your application connects to.  If you add data at run time you're adding it to that copy.  If you examine the database in VS, you're examining the source file.  That's why you don't see the data in VS.

By default, the source file is copied into the output folder on every build, overwriting any existing file.  That means that if you add data, stop the debugger, make a code change and then run the project again, your data will go bye-byes because the file it was added to has been overwritten.  You can prevent that by selecting the file in the Solution Explorer and setting the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if Newer`.  That way, your working file will only ever be overwritten if you make changes to the source file, e.g. when you update the schema.

In short, don't expect to see test data via VS and don't expect to keep test data between runs by default.

Comment: ohhh now I get it. pheew.. thanks for the big big info sir and with that in mind its A-Okey now, I got it working now. in addition to that haha I was silly enough not to notice that my Data Source was missing some especially the path in my computer where it is located... sorry for being noob at this. I was very much enlightened with what you said. Thanks again and more power!